# Why do my account's rank appear in the top of the second page of the list, while it is not deserved the position?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, user-experience, rankings, user-rank

[My rank in Academia](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/191/alltime/academia/2012-02-14?sort=reputationchange&page=2) is 235, yet it appears in the top of the second page of the list.

I know that this is for me to easier check to rank, but putting me there will make me a (quick) false impression that I've made it to the top. The subtle yellow is too... subtle, and I only check my rep, *after* I have the mis-impression. I come here for the rank, not the rep, so if there is no disparate my brain will interpret it as a rank . I'm fine with seeing my account easier, but at least make a distinction in the UI/UX so that I won't have that false impression.

What do you think?

[image: image description]

Comment: In response to your question `What do you think?` - I think it is fine as it is, never had any problems with the current layout - that is just me though.

Comment: What's that ranking thing you are talking about? :P

Comment: @DeerHunter well, I just expect a real 31 position in the top

Comment: It is a quicker way to see your rank and rep earned for that time period. This eliminates the need of searching through every single page to look for your username.